# Keycloak Client settings, what URLs do I need?

Tags: keycloak, thorntail

I have problems setting up Keycloak for a project I do.
Keycloak is running on `http://localhost:8180`.
Thorntail server is running on `http://localhost:8080/users` which serves data for an
Angular frontend on `http://localhost:4200/*`. What I want to do is that a User can only see `http://localhost:4200/sign-in` without logging in. Once logged in they can access for example `http://localhost:4200/list-user`.
[I was using this guide to set up Keycloak](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/keycloak/securing-a-microprofile-application-with-keycloak), but I'm not sure what I my Client settings should be. This is what I thought:

Root URL: `http://localhost:4200/sign-in`

*Valid Redirect URIs: `http://localhost:4200/list-user`

Base URL: `http://localhost:4200/sign-in`

Admin URL: `http://localhost:8080`

Somebody please explain the purpose of these settings as I struggle to understand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Root url is just a value that will be used for relative paths resolving.

- Root: `http://localhost:4200/sign-in`
- Valid Redirects: `/*` (After login user could be redirected to any URI that matches pattern `http://localhost:4200/sign-in/*`)
- Base URL: `/` (Is not mandatory. Used when keycloak need to calculate application url by **client_id** only)
- Admin URL: `/` (Used when Keycloak need to notify applications about revocation or when user logs out. For example when user logs out in application A if he has session in application B, Keycloak will send **backchannel** request to Admin URL of application B, so Application B will also flush user session in it)

Check out docs and info badges in Admin Console

Comment: I still don't understand Base URL, can you elaborate on this? I went to the documentation which says "This URL is used when Keycloak needs to link to the client" still I don't get what is the difference between this and root url

Comment: @Ahmad root URL never used directly, it's just a feature to reduce copy-pasting in other URL fields (base URL, redirect URIs, Admin URL etc...)